# How to have multi options list for one function?

Tags: go, design-patterns

I am using options pattern to configure the behavior of function, there are two function `Foo` and `Bar` which one dependent on the other, the code as follow

```golang
type fooOptions struct {
    fooName string
}

type FooOptions func(*fooOptions)

func WithFooName(fooName string) {
    return func(options *fooOptions) {
        options.fooName = fooName
    }
}

func Foo(options ...FooOptions) {
    opts := &fooOptions{}
    for _, opt := range options {
        opt(opts)
    }

    // do something
}

type barOptions struct {
    barName string
}

type BarOptions func(*barOptions)


func WithBarName(barName string) {
    return func(options *barOptions) {
        options.barName = barName
    }
}

// compile error,unable have multi options list
func Bar(boptions ...BarOptions,fOptions ...FooOptions) {
    bopts := &barOptions{}
    for _, opt := range boptions {
        opt(bopts)
    }
    Foo(fOptions...)
}
```

I wonder how can I have multi options list for the Bar function,or any other smart way, so I can reuse the code, otherwise I have to flatten `fooOptions` into `barOptions` and writing the `withXXX` again

Comment: Accept a slice, stylistically speaking it should a slice of foo options and a variadic list of bar options. `Bar(fOptions []FooOptions, boptions ...BarOptions)`.

Comment: Alternative would be to have a `WithFooOptions(...FooOptions)` that returns a `BarOptions` func.

Comment: I, for one, would prefer `WithFooOptions`.

Comment: If you're taking two sets of options into the same function, this indicates a design flaw somewhere. It's hard to say from a contrived example, but in this scenario I would look to refactor whatever is causing it to need two sets of unrelated options.